# Removing unused CSS from website code level

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, performance

In our project, we have around 50-60 scss files. All the scss files are getting compiled into one css file.  When page loads, CSS file is getting loaded.  Is there any way to remove unused CSS based on page navigation.  Home have different unused css compared to another page in same application.  Please suggest simpler way to remove unused css based on each page

Answer (score 0):

You can detect unused CSS through the chrome coverage tool. Include CSS to page-level so it will not load globally.

[image]